# How to make use of UUIDGEN of unix in perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to generate a unique number using uuidgen (of unix). The generated unique number should get stored in a variable. When i am doing it in a function , I am facing errors.

Can anyone let me know how to make use of uuidgen script in perl.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    sub function_uuidgen
    {
       my myuuid;

       system(`export myuuid=uuidgen`);
       print "\n unique id is : $myuuid";

       # I need not to export the variable, I just need to unique number generated by UUID GENERATOR in a variable.
     }

     int main
     {
        print "\n I am in main function";
        &function_uuidgen;
     }
```

I am facing the below error when I am running uuidgen as mentioned below. Can anybody help me out with exporting the JAVA VARIABLE in perl ? How to export the path variable,in case if this error is related to that.

Error :

```
         /bin/java: uuidgen 1: not found
```

Code :

```
   sub function_uuidgen
    {

   my $myuuid = qx(uuidgen);
   chomp $myuuid;

   print "\n unique id is : $myuuid";

   # I need to export the variable, as it is giving me error without exporting.
    }

   int main
   {
    print "\n I am in main function";
    function_uuidgen();
   }
```

Comment: When adding code, please run it first. Your code is not runnable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you for some reason can't use Data::GUID, this is a way to use the output of uuidgen (note the backticks):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $uuid=`uuidgen`;
chomp $uuid;

print "$uuid\n";
```

Example output:

```
$ ./hep.pl 
fe82c4f6-a1f2-4242-ab45-853780931927
$
```

Also, using & before function calls went out of fashion many years ago :-)

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing up C and Perl here.
As far as I know you can't access exportet system variables that way from perl (correct me if I am wrong. I don't have much knowledge of linux system variables).

A way to generate UUID's would be the [Data::GUID](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aGUID) Module from CPAN

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::GUID qw( guid_string );

my $guid = guid_string();
print "$guid\n";
```

Also Perl doesn't have an `int main` function. Your code starts at the top and runs down to the bottom. Of course this gets a bit different if you create an object orientated module.

Comment: +1 for recommending a Perl module instead of depending upon a system executable.

Comment: By the way, I like [UUID::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/UUID::Tiny). It's not as popular, but needs fewer dependencies and is a pure Perl solution.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything about uuidgen: You could just

```
my $perlVar = `uuidgen`;
```

within perl.
Assuming calling uuidgen in your console returns the number you are looking for.

Comment: @All: I am facing error in I think exporting the path. I am gettin the below mentioned error when I am trying to make use of uuidgen in my code. /bin/java: uuidgen 1: not found

Comment: with perl version v5.26.1 getting error "Can't exec "uuidgen": No such file or directory", however the same is working with perl v5.16.3 version.

Answer (score 2):

`export` is a shell command that adds a variable and value to its environment block.  The environment block is private to a process, but (by default) copied to a child process.  You appear to be thinking it is some sort of global area - it is not.

So, all you would be doing is adding a value to the shell's environment block, not your own!  (That's the shell created by `system()`, not the one you were running from).  Placing the `export` inside back-ticks is strange, if not wrong.

Easier to use:

```
my $myuuid = qx(uuidgen);
chomp $myuuid;
```

Notice I am using `qx` instead of back-ticks `` because they can be confusing (back-ticks are deprecated in UNIX shells as well).

To run the subroutine, loose the C style `int main`:

```
print "\n I am in ", __PACKAGE__, "package\n";
function_uuidgen();
```

The leading `&` on a subroutine call has side-effects that you probably don't need.

Comment: I like to consider `\`\`` as a shortcut of `qx\`\``.